# PhpStorm Field accessed via magic method

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpstorm

I have ignited datatables Library in my CodeIgniter library folder.

Some Code from Library

```
class Datatables
{
    /**
     * Global container variables for chained argument results
     *
     */
    protected $ci;
    protected $table;
    protected $distinct;
    protected $group_by;
    protected $select         = array();
    protected $joins          = array();
    protected $columns        = array();
    protected $where          = array();
    protected $filter         = array();
    protected $add_columns    = array();
    protected $edit_columns   = array();
    protected $unset_columns  = array();

    /**
     * Copies an instance of CI
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }
```

Then I called the library in model

```
class Common_Model extends MY_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('Datatables.php');
    }
```

then I tried to call the library functions

```
function select_fields_joined_DT($data, $PTable, $joins = '', $where = '', $addColumn = '',$unsetColumn='')
{
    /**
     *
     */
    $this->datatables->select($data);
    if ($unsetColumn != '') {
        unset_column($unsetColumn);
    }
        $this->datatables->from($PTable);
    if ($joins != '') {
        foreach ($joins as $k => $v) {
            //$this->datatables->join($v['table'], $v['condition'], $v['type']);
        }
    }

    if ($addColumn != '') {
        $this->datatables->add_column("Actions", $addColumn);
    }

    $result = $this->datatables->generate();
    return $result;
}
```

and everything works fine, except that the phpstorm shows me this error:

```
Field Accessed via magic method
```

[image]

I tried to remove this error with document comments but can't figure out how can I do that..
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to declare them via `@property` in PHPDoc comment that belongs to that class.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without touching the file that the class is declared in? For example, if the class is part of a third-party library, and I don't want to make custom patches to that code just to add these `@property` comments?

Comment: @Enno Did you find an answer to your question? I'm also having the same problem as yours. The only way I can think of is to create a class extending the third-party class and then add the `@property`? Not sure if it'll work though.

Comment: @markandrewkato I think it depends a lot on your situation whether you can extend the class or not. In my case, it wasn't possible, and to be honest, I no longer remember what I did.

Comment: @Enno No problem. Since I can't add a doc to third party and I don't want to extend neither, I just followed the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 141):

Edit: Just because I keep getting upvotes for this, I want to preface this answer with a caveat. I inherited an old project that I would not be working on long term nor be paid to properly type everything.  I consider the below a nuclear option and would only do so under similar conditions.  If this is a project you own or will at least be working with a long time, especially in modern PHP 7/8 and beyond era, please don't do this and tidy up your code instead with actual types or at least a docblock :)  Original answer follows below.

If you want to remove this without document comments you can uncheck **Notify about access to a property via magic method** which is found in

**Project Settings** > **Inspections** > **PHP** > **Undefined** > **Undefined property**

[image: Notify about access to a field via magic method]

[PhpStorm preferences screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TcbF.png)

Comment: Not sure whether to laugh or cry.  I switched from Idea to stand alone phpstorm recently and having this problem again I googled this notification to find this SO question.  I did not like the upvoted answer and found @LazyOne's comment to be what I was looking for.  Then realized this answer was mine...

Comment: I made LazyOne's comment a community answer. Feel free to add to it or correct the information.

Comment: Well done. I am facing now this issue. I am little bit used to PyCharm with Python relations, of course. I am new to PhpStorm. It was easy to find out this route and uncheck Undefined property. This is good because as I am working with Laravel...happens all the time! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Bitart check out https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper  I don't run into undefineds anymore with that

Comment: Just couldn't help myself from laughing at chrisan's comment.

Comment: In laravel we can't declare @property because it is relationship behind the scenes. Any tips?

Comment: @keizah7 have you tried laravel ide helper?

Comment: I trying find a way without ide helper

Answer (score 58):

[As mentioned by **LazyOne**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578649/phpstorm-field-accessed-via-magic-method#comment39953964_25578649) in the question comments:

> You have to declare them via `@property` in PHPDoc comment that
>   belongs to that class.

```
/**
 * @property string $bar
 */
class Foo {

    public function __get($name) {
        if ($name == 'bar') {
            return 'bar';
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

*Snippet from Dmitry Dulepov's article ["Quick tip: magic methods and PhpStorm"](https://web.archive.org/web/20170126122945/http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2012/08/quick-tip-magic-methods-and-phpstorm.html).*

Comment: The link to the article is no longer valid.

Comment: @CraigLondon the article isn't needed as everything is in the answer and the link was only provided as a source. Still, I updated it with a [wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/) snapshot link.

Comment: I honestly like this a lot more than the chosen answer. It gives a way to explicitly say what we can expect from a class rather than just leaving it all up to magic and possible typing errors

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to disable the inspection for the whole project, and can't modify the class file to add a `@property` tag, this is how to suppress the warning at the location where it is used:

```
/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedFieldInspection */
```

Just add it in a new line right before the line where the magic field is used.

Comment: May be you can refer to the official documentation on this topic to be more helpful :
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-inspection.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections

Answer (score 4):

[@christian answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26314659/4742972) is still valid, but the path for disabling the inspection recently changed.

Here is the new one:

**Preferences > Editor > Inspections > PHP > Undefined Symbols > Undefied property**

Then disable the "Notify of access to a property via magic method".